# Cancel those hung print jobs

Tags: ruby, regex, server, ssh

I've created a program that will list all hung print jobs on a specified server, from there it will load them and strip the jobs down to their `Job ID` then cancel the jobs on that server only.

I would like a critique of my work please.

- How does this look as an OOP script?
- Is there anything I can do differently?
- Is calling the `Net::SSH.start` twice really necessary?

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'

class PrintJobs

  HOST = ARGV[0]
  USERNAME = Etc.getlogin
  PASSWORD = nil

  def scan_for_jobs
    check_jobs = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USERNAME, :password => PASSWORD) do |ssh|
      cmd = "prt_jobs"
      info = ssh.exec!(cmd)
      if info == nil
        puts "No print jobs on server #{HOST}"
      else
        res = info.split("\n").reject {|line| line.match(/\s+2016\s+/)}.join("\n")
        puts res
        print "Process into kill que: "
        input = STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase
        if input == "YES"
          kill_que(check_jobs, res)
        else
          exit 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def kill_que(check_jobs, res)
    puts "Loading jobs into kill que.."
    column = 0
    job_ids = res.lines.map { |job| job.split(/\s+/)[0] }.each do |task_id|
      kill_jobs(task_id)
    end
  end

  def kill_jobs(task_id)
    execute = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USERNAME, :password => PASSWORD)
    id_to_strip = task_id.gsub(/\-/," ")
    column = 1
    stripping_id = id_to_strip.lines.map { |task| task.split(/\s+/)[1] }.each do |id|
      id.strip
      puts "Cancelling job: #{id}"
      #`sudo cancel #{id}`
      execute.exec!("sudo cancel #{id}")
    end
  end
end

killer = PrintJobs.new
killer.scan_for_jobs
```

Usage example:

```
closing_2-254128        root            933888   Thu 03 Dec 2015 03:49:13 PM CST
closing_2-254129        root            933888   Thu 03 Dec 2015 03:50:16 PM CST
laser42-254144          root            192512   Thu 03 Dec 2015 04:24:02 PM CST
laser42-254145          root            171008   Thu 03 Dec 2015 04:25:10 PM CST
ship_audit-254143       root            141312   Thu 03 Dec 2015 04:23:13 PM CST
Process into kill que: yes
Loading jobs into kill que..
Cancelling job: 254128
Cancelling job: 254129
Cancelling job: 254144
Cancelling job: 254145
Cancelling job: 254143

No print jobs on server
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. You should be able to use the variable that you set the `Net::SSH` too instead of calling it twice, try passing it as an argument to the method, call it, and do an `exec!` on it.

Comment: This isn't really OOP.

Comment: @EBrown A for effort lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping your methods in a class definition isn't the same thing as making your project OOP. These methods don't care about their receiver, and forcing the programmer to instantiate the PrintJobs class before calling them doesn't accomplish anything useful here. Now, for special-purpose scripts like this, not being OO isn't the worst thing in the world - in fact, going OO can be design overkill for a project this small. However, if you go the functional route, tell it like it is - refactor `class PrintJobs` to `module PrintJobs` (because `Module` is, idiomatically, the correct type for a collection of associated methods) so that you can do your invocation with `PrintJobs.scan_for_jobs`.

If you want to convert the code to be more OO - to make it easier to incorporate into another project, for example - objects need to be responsible for the data they operate on. That means that the HOST/USERNAME/PASSWORD values need to be instance variables, not class constants. You also want to be sure that your data is typed appropriately. Currently, there's a lot of passing around and manipulation of strings that represent print jobs. If the output format of `prt_jobs` ever changes, we'll need to update every piece of code that interacts with these objects. Abstracting them into their own type will help prevent this.

Stylistic touches:

- Get rid of extraneous definitions - `cmd` is defined and then only used once, in the immediately following line. Some other variables are defined and then never used.
- Avoid abbreviation. I assume `res` means "results", but I'm not sure.
- Exiting with a non-zero status code should only happen if the program encounters some sort of error, which isn't the case with your usage. I'd remove the statement entirely, since there's no real reason for `PrintJobs` to be responsible for program termination anyway.
- Last but not least, the word is "queue".

Here's the class refactored, with additional comments in-line. Since I don't have a print server handy the code has not been tested and probably contains bugs, but it should give you an idea of what a more object-oriented structure looks like.

```
class PrintManager
  # I've made the PrintJob class belong to PrintManager for now,
  # but you could move it to global scope if it becomes handy elsewhere
  class PrintJob
    attr_reader :printer, :id, :user, :some_other_thing, :date

    def initialize(printer, id, user, some_other_thing, date)
      @printer, @id, @user = printer, id, user
      @some_other_thing, @date = some_other_thing, date
    end

    # If the output of `prt_jobs` ever changes, this is the only code you'll
    # need to update.
    # In real life we'd want to parse the time into a proper Time object.
    def self.parse(job_string)
      job_string =~ /^(\S+)-(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s*$/
      return self.new($1, $2.to_i, $3, $4.to_i, $5)
    end

    def to_s
      "#{@printer}-#{@id}\t#{@user}\t#{@some_other_thing}\t#{@date}"
    end
  end

  def initialize(host, username, password)
    @host, @username, @password = host, username, password
  end

  def scan_for_jobs
    Net::SSH.start(@host, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
      info = ssh.exec!("prt_jobs")
      if info == nil
        puts "No print jobs on server #{@host}"
      else
        # The old "res" object we got here was a big blobby String.
        # Now we have an Array of PrintJobs, which is much easier
        # to interact with.
        print_jobs = info.split("\n").map {|line|
          PrintJob.parse(line)
        }
        print_jobs.reject! {|job| job.date.match(/\s+2016\s+/) }

        # One disadvantage of parsing out the string at object
        # creation is that we lose formatting, and our tab stops
        # may not line up without some extra effort. Oh well!
        puts print_jobs
        print "Kill these jobs (yes/no): "
        input = STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase
        if input == "YES"
          # The kill_queue method only really existed to do string
          # parsing. We accidentally made it unnecessary when we made
          # PrintJob a real class.
          print_jobs.each { |job| kill_job(job, ssh)}
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Since kill_job is only called from within scan_for_jobs, we'll
  # just reuse its SSH object. Depending on how your program grows, it
  # may be better to have kill_job open its own SSH connection like
  # you had originally, or make it an attribute of PrintManager, or
  # something else. 
  def kill_job(job, ssh)
    # Got to remove a bunch more string parsing here
    puts "Cancelling job: #{job.id}"
    ssh.exec!("sudo cancel #{job.id}")
  end
end

killer = PrintManager.new(ARGV[0], Etc.getlogin, nil)
killer.scan_for_jobs
```

Comment: I can tell you why they use `nil`, `net/ssh` has a required password argument, don't ask me why, I don't know, but passing it `nil` gives it the required arguments along with the no sensitive information..

Comment: @Ekult3k I was actually referring to the line `if info == nil`.

Comment: oh, I'm guessing that if the `prt_jobs` command shows nothing then it says `no print jobs on server`, that's kind of obvious isn't it..? What happens in bash is when you call the command `prt_jobs` if there's none on the server it doesn't return anything.. So if `info == nil` output that there's no hung print jobs on the server...

Comment: @Ekult3k No, I get what OP is trying to do, but if `prt_jobs` produces no output then `exec!` returns the empty string, which is distinct from `nil`, so the `if` condition is never satisfied. I'll try to edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Oh I understand what you're saying.. I misread you, that's my bad! But having said that,, `nil` would be the same as an empty string wouldn't it?

Comment: @Ekult3k Nope, `nil` is its own value with its own distinct type. It doesn't evaluate as equal to any other value in the language. And in Ruby, the empty string isn't particularly special (some other languages do treat it as a uniquely falsey value, but that's still not the same thing as being equal to `nil`/`null`/`None`).

Comment: Then wouldn't that make this broken code? Because it doesn't output that specific string if there's no jobs on the server?

Comment: Only @Bam can say for sure which version(s) are broken since I can't test the code. But yes, since this is a matter of functionality rather than good style I probably should have left that bit well enough alone.

Comment: @ezrast So, it does output the stuff, it is working, I have cancelled over 5,000 jobs with it myself, so I guess I'm not understanding you.. Should I have used `.empty?` instead of nil?

Comment: @ezrast and on top of that I'm running bash commands not strings, it doesn't return and empty string because it runs it as a bash command from the terminal, hence why `nil` works..

Comment: @Bam That's interesting - I can't get `exec!` to ever return anything but a `String` but if you're getting the `No print jobs on server` message when appropriate (that's the only part I was calling into question, not whether you could cancel jobs) then I must be mistaken. Sorry to cause confusion.

Comment: @ezrast All good, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Bug / useless line**

In the block of code:

```
  id.strip
  puts "Cancelling job: #{id}"
  #`sudo cancel #{id}`
  execute.exec!("sudo cancel #{id}")
```

`id.strip` generates a value to be immediately discarded, essentially a no-op.

In Ruby immutability is the default: look at the following IRB session for clarification:

```
irb(main):001:0> x= " foo"
=> " foo"
irb(main):002:0> x.strip
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> x
=> " foo"
irb(main):004:0> x.strip!
=> "foo"
irb(main):005:0> x
=> "foo"
```

The line does not actually strip the name causing a bug -> use the in-place version `id.strip!` (Note the final `!`)

Comment: Why do you have to use the `!`? I thought it would work either way

Comment: @Bam `.strip` does not modify the value stored in the variable, only methods ending with `!` modify the variable (and very few others)

Comment: @Caridorc I don't think this is a bug, more of a useless call,  it doesn't matter if there's  a space because bash will ignore trailing white space, won't it?